# BULK INSERT into table and auto-increment

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, bulkinsert, data-import

I have a `.txt` file in the format:

```
123456
111111
122222
123344
121212
```

I wish to insert these into a temporary table along with an integer recording the order in which they are in the `.txt` file, such as:

```
Index    Number
---------------
1        123456
2        111111
3        122222
4        123344
5        121212
```

Currently I'm doing this by having an `IDENTITY` column in my temporary table and doing a `BULK INSERT` using a `FORMATFILE` like so:

```
CREATE TABLE #tbl
(   
    idx int NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    ItemNumber nchar(6)
)


BULK INSERT #tbl 
FROM 'd:\MyNumberList.txt'
WITH 
(
     FORMATFILE='d:\MyFormatFile.xml'
)
```

However, I'm hoping theres a way of achieving this without the need for a `FORMATFILE` file.

Is there a way of doing this?

Comment: Is this for **Data Migration**

Comment: @Luv Its just an import process.

Comment: You can use **SSIS Package.**

Comment: I don't see what's wrong with your current solution: is removing the format file really much "simpler"? If you do a lot of bulk imports, it's common to have a 'library' of format files that you can use for various source file formats.

Comment: @Pondlife Having the format file means I need to keep a reference to this whereever this script is placed in the future, across different servers. I'd rather not rely on this file.

Comment: @Luv Can you please elaborate? Perhaps with an answer or a link.

Comment: @Curt Sure, but you also have to reference the .txt file, which presents exactly the same issues

Comment: @Pondlife The `txt` file will eventually be a SQL parameter. I don't wish to make the formatfile a parameter also.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a `view`. However, because you are using a temporary table here, and it's not possible to create a view on a temporary table, you'd addtionally need to make use of a synonym.

If you were importing into a regular table, you wouldn't need the synonym:

```
create synonym tbl for #tbl
GO

create view vtbl
as
select ItemNumber from tbl
GO

bulk insert vtbl from 'd:\MyNumberList.txt'
GO

select * from #tbl
GO
```